# Can we sell the physical goods using ERC721?

Tags: etherscan, nft, alchemy

I'm new to this. can anyopne provide any feddback to the following things:

1. I need to build the marketplace to sell physical goods.
2. Can we sell the physical goods using ERC721?
3. I need to update the metadata after publish, Is it possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely use erc721 to make validate or facilitate  physical purchases. For example, your website to ship an item might check the wallet of a user before the shipping option is made available. Then, it could even determine exactly which item is being shipped by the tokenId. Ultimately, your erc721 will be the redemption ticket for your customer.

As for Metadata, it is common practice for it to point to an IPFS endpoint. This data can be adjusted at any time before, during, and after sale of your ERC721.